# Windows Ignores Sleep Settings - randomly accepts or rejects settings

Tags: windows, windows-10, sleep, power

I have an Acer Nitro 5 laptop, purchased in June 2018, running Windows 10. Everything up to date. I currently have it on a custom plan for high performance, but even when defaults are restored it is ignoring my sleep settings, and it is doing so at random.

Right now, the computer goes to sleep after 90 seconds to 2 minutes of inactivity. I can reset the system a few times, and it will work with the current settings (sleep after 2 hours). It will work for maybe minutes, maybe hours, maybe days: and then it stops working and reverts back to sleeping after 90 - 120 seconds. And then it's stuck doing that until I reset again, and then it sometimes starts off correctly as per the plan, and sometimes just immediately reverts to ignoring sleep settings.

Screen saver settings are to None, with Wait grayed out (90 minutes being the time grayed out) and On resume, display login screen unchecked

Under Power and Sleep:

Screen: 
On battery power, turn off after (2 hours)
When plugged in, turn off after (Never)

Sleep:
On battery power, PC goes to sleep after (2 hours)
When plugged in, PC goes to sleep after (4 hours)

In advanced Power Options,

Turn off hard disk after:
On battery (15 mins)
Plugged in (20 mins)

Sleep, sleep after:
On battery (120 mins)
Plugged in (240 mins)

Allow hybrid sleep:
On battery (off)
Plugged in (off)

Hibernate after:
On battery (240 mins)
Plugged in (Never)

Display, turn off after:
On battery (120 mins)
Plugged in (Never)

I ran a troubleshooter on the Power settings, and the only issue that is surfaced is it says I am running a High Performance setting, and I should switch to a balanced plan to save energy (I would like to keep my custom high performance plan, but again when this is in balanced as per WIndows suggestion it exhibits the same erratic behavior)

I am really at a loss. I've tried everything, googled and trialed everything, there is nothing I can do that I know of aside from restore factory settings - please someone help me avoid having to do this. Thank you in advance for your time and help